# Where can I find the controller for a magento backend module?

Tags: php, magento, module

I need to amend the reviews section of a magento backend. The form I need to amend is the one you see when the "Add New Review" is clicked, and the controller for this.

Where can I find these files?

Comment: the generated url should tell you which controller is used...

Comment: What is the generated url? How to know what file to amend?

Comment: if you click on add new review... which url is in your addressbar?

Comment: www.blablalb.com/index.php/admin/catalog_product_review/new/key/b54d4de2d393c742502dd39438a6f08d/ this is my url when I click on the "Add New"

Comment: Simpy ammending the form does not help you in adding something to the database... it's more extensive than that... Try reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084144/add-custom-fields-in-review-form first

Comment: I have already read that question, it doesn't help it is modifing a core magento file. I know it is not only html what I need to amend. I need to know in what path to find the form/controller, I am succesfully saving the "Edit" form but I cannot figure out how to do the same for "Add New"

Comment: What version of magento are you using?

Comment: It is Magento 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php
```

Method:

```
postAction()
```

Base template file used (specific is depending on your theme):

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/review/form.phtml
```

For the backend:

Controller:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/ReviewController.php
```

Method:

```
newAction()
```

Base template file used:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/review/add.phtml
```

Comment: None of those files seem to be the right ones. I have already tried to modify those files but amending them does not make any difference. When I say backend I mean "not frontend", so the form you can see when logged in on magento.

Comment: I have an extension installed which allows users to add images to reviews, may it be interfering?

Comment: @human If it's a really bad plugin, it could... Try the suggested files first though...

Comment: Spot on for the controller. But the form doesn't seem to be the one I need.

Comment: @human What are you trying to achieve in the end? Because like this we keep going back and forth....

Comment: You have already answered 50% of my question. What I need is to add an "image" field to the "Add New" form.

Comment: And your plugin probably already added the image to the fieldlist of the review... So only the displaying and saving of this field should be done in the backend?

Comment: Yes that is exactly it.

Comment: Is it a free plugin? And which one is it?

Comment: This is the one: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-review-form-with-image-field.html

Comment: After reviewing the plugin-code, I see they didnt add the field to the fieldset, but they store the image in a separate table. This complicates things, because you have to add the image to the fieldset so you can use it in the backend... I'm sorry, but the solution to this is beyond the time I have to answer you here...