# Custom fields are not saving in magento product review

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to add extra fields in magento product review.
1. Good thing about product
2. Bad thing about product

I follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084144/add-custom-fields-in-review-form). I have override core files into my local files.
Here my code:

> template/review/form.phtml

```
<li>
     <label for="goodthings" class="required"><?php echo $this->__('Good Things') ?></label>
     <div class="input-box">
     <textarea name="goodthings" id="goodthings" cols="5" rows="3" ><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($data->getGoodthings()) ?></textarea>
     </div>

</li>
<li>
    <label for="badthings" class="required"><?php echo $this->__('Bad Things') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
    <textarea name="badthings" id="badthings" cols="5" rows="3" ><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($data->getBadthings()) ?></textarea>
     </div></li>
```

and

> /local/Mage/Review/Model/Resource/Review.php

```
$detail = array(
            'title'     => $object->getTitle(),
            'detail'    => $object->getDetail(),
            'nickname'  => $object->getNickname(),
            'goodthing' => $object->getGoodthings(), 
            'badthing' => $object->getBadthings(),
        );
```

Database query:

```
ALTER TABLE  `review_detail` ADD  `goodthing` TEXT NOT NULL COMMENT  'review goodthing' AFTER  `nickname` ,
ADD  `badthing` TEXT NOT NULL COMMENT  'review badthing' AFTER  `goodthing` ;
```

> /local/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php

```
class Mage_Review_ProductController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    /**
     * Action list where need check enabled cookie
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_cookieCheckActions = array('post');

    public function preDispatch()
    {
        parent::preDispatch();

        $allowGuest = Mage::helper('review')->getIsGuestAllowToWrite();
        if (!$this->getRequest()->isDispatched()) {
            return;
        }

        $action = strtolower($this->getRequest()->getActionName());
        if (!$allowGuest && $action == 'post' && $this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
                $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current' => true)));
                Mage::getSingleton('review/session')->setFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost())
                    ->setRedirectUrl($this->_getRefererUrl());
                $this->_redirectUrl(Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl());
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Initialize and check product
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
     */
    protected function _initProduct()
    {
        Mage::dispatchEvent('review_controller_product_init_before', array('controller_action'=>$this));
        $categoryId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('category', false);
        $productId  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

        $product = $this->_loadProduct($productId);
        if (!$product) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($categoryId) {
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
            Mage::register('current_category', $category);
        }

        try {
            Mage::dispatchEvent('review_controller_product_init', array('product'=>$product));
            Mage::dispatchEvent('review_controller_product_init_after', array(
                'product'           => $product,
                'controller_action' => $this
            ));
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);
            return false;
        }

        return $product;
    }

    /**
     * Load product model with data by passed id.
     * Return false if product was not loaded or has incorrect status.
     *
     * @param int $productId
     * @return bool|Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
     */
    protected function _loadProduct($productId)
    {
        if (!$productId) {
            return false;
        }

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->load($productId);
        /* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
        if (!$product->getId() || !$product->isVisibleInCatalog() || !$product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility()) {
            return false;
        }

        Mage::register('current_product', $product);
        Mage::register('product', $product);

        return $product;
    }

    /**
     * Load review model with data by passed id.
     * Return false if review was not loaded or review is not approved.
     *
     * @param int $productId
     * @return bool|Mage_Review_Model_Review
     */
    protected function _loadReview($reviewId)
    {
        if (!$reviewId) {
            return false;
        }

        $review = Mage::getModel('review/review')->load($reviewId);
        /* @var $review Mage_Review_Model_Review */
        if (!$review->getId() || !$review->isApproved() || !$review->isAvailableOnStore(Mage::app()->getStore())) {
            return false;
        }

        Mage::register('current_review', $review);

        return $review;
    }

    /**
     * Submit new review action
     *
     */
    public function postAction()
    {
        if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
            // returns to the product item page
            $this->_redirectReferer();
            return;
        }

        if ($data = Mage::getSingleton('review/session')->getFormData(true)) {
            $rating = array();
            if (isset($data['ratings']) && is_array($data['ratings'])) {
                $rating = $data['ratings'];
            }
        } else {
            $data   = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            $rating = $this->getRequest()->getParam('ratings', array());
        }

        if (($product = $this->_initProduct()) && !empty($data)) {
            $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
            /* @var $session Mage_Core_Model_Session */
            $review = Mage::getModel('review/review')->setData($this->_cropReviewData($data));
            /* @var $review Mage_Review_Model_Review */

            $validate = $review->validate();
            if ($validate === true) {
                try {
                    $review->setEntityId($review->getEntityIdByCode(Mage_Review_Model_Review::ENTITY_PRODUCT_CODE))
                        ->setEntityPkValue($product->getId())
                        ->setStatusId(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_PENDING)
                        ->setCustomerId(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId())
                        ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                        ->setStores(array(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()))
                        ->save();

                    foreach ($rating as $ratingId => $optionId) {
                        Mage::getModel('rating/rating')
                        ->setRatingId($ratingId)
                        ->setReviewId($review->getId())
                        ->setCustomerId(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId())
                        ->addOptionVote($optionId, $product->getId());
                    }

                    $review->aggregate();
                    $session->addSuccess($this->__('Your review has been accepted for moderation.'));
                }
                catch (Exception $e) {
                    $session->setFormData($data);
                    $session->addError($this->__('Unable to post the review.'));
                }
            }
            else {
                $session->setFormData($data);
                if (is_array($validate)) {
                    foreach ($validate as $errorMessage) {
                        $session->addError($errorMessage);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $session->addError($this->__('Unable to post the review.'));
                }
            }
        }

        if ($redirectUrl = Mage::getSingleton('review/session')->getRedirectUrl(true)) {
            $this->_redirectUrl($redirectUrl);
            return;
        }
        $this->_redirectReferer();
    }

    /**
     * Show list of product's reviews
     *
     */
    public function listAction()
    {
        if ($product = $this->_initProduct()) {
            Mage::register('productId', $product->getId());

            $design = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/design');
            $settings = $design->getDesignSettings($product);
            if ($settings->getCustomDesign()) {
                $design->applyCustomDesign($settings->getCustomDesign());
            }
            $this->_initProductLayout($product);

            // update breadcrumbs
            if ($breadcrumbsBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')) {
                $breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb('product', array(
                    'label'    => $product->getName(),
                    'link'     => $product->getProductUrl(),
                    'readonly' => true,
                ));
                $breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb('reviews', array('label' => Mage::helper('review')->__('Product Reviews')));
            }

            $this->renderLayout();
        } elseif (!$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
            $this->_forward('noRoute');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Show details of one review
     *
     */
    public function viewAction()
    {
        $review = $this->_loadReview((int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
        if (!$review) {
            $this->_forward('noroute');
            return;
        }

        $product = $this->_loadProduct($review->getEntityPkValue());
        if (!$product) {
            $this->_forward('noroute');
            return;
        }

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('review/session');
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    /**
     * Load specific layout handles by product type id
     *
     */
    protected function _initProductLayout($product)
    {
        $update = $this->getLayout()->getUpdate();

        $update->addHandle('default');
        $this->addActionLayoutHandles();


        $update->addHandle('PRODUCT_TYPE_'.$product->getTypeId());

        if ($product->getPageLayout()) {
            $this->getLayout()->helper('page/layout')
                ->applyHandle($product->getPageLayout());
        }

        $this->loadLayoutUpdates();
        if ($product->getPageLayout()) {
            $this->getLayout()->helper('page/layout')
                ->applyTemplate($product->getPageLayout());
        }
        $update->addUpdate($product->getCustomLayoutUpdate());
        $this->generateLayoutXml()->generateLayoutBlocks();
    }

    /**
     * Crops POST values
     * @param array $reviewData
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _cropReviewData(array $reviewData)
    {
        $croppedValues = array();
        $allowedKeys = array_fill_keys(array('detail', 'title', 'nickname','goodthings','badthings'), true);

        foreach ($reviewData as $key => $value) {
            if (isset($allowedKeys[$key])) {
                $croppedValues[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        return $croppedValues;
    }
}
```

form after submit not saving value of custom fields but default field are saving to database, i have tried to debug with `Mage::log();` and i am getting value for all fields in my controller on submit but not getting in Model and no log print in my Model.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue, but was able to solve it. Below are the steps:
1) my phtml file: added a custom field 'Email'

```
<li>
    <label for="email_field" class="required"><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?> :</label>
    <div class="input-box">
       <input type="text" name="email" id="email_field" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" class="form-control validate-email" placeholder="Enter your Email" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your Email'" />
    </div>
</li>
```

2) Created sql script to add new field to **review_detail** table

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->getConnection()
   ->addColumn(
        $installer->getTable('review/review_detail'),
        'customer_email',array(
            'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'nullable'  => false,
            'length'    => 255,
            'after'     => 'detail',
            'comment'   => 'Customer Email'
          )
      );
$installer->endSetup();
```

3) Override **Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php** and edit method **_cropReviewData**

```
protected function _cropReviewData(array $reviewData)
{
    $croppedValues = array();
    $allowedKeys = array_fill_keys(array('detail', 'title', 'nickname','customer_email'), true);

    foreach ($reviewData as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($allowedKeys[$key])) {
            $croppedValues[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $croppedValues;
}
```

we have added our custom field **customer_email** to array
3) Override **Mage_Review_Model_Resource_Review.php** and edit method **_afterSave** and add custom field to **$detail** array

```
$detail = array(
        'title'     => $object->getTitle(),
        'detail'    => $object->getDetail(),
        'nickname'  => $object->getNickname(),
        'customer_email' => $object->getCustomerEmail(),
    );
```

After doing the above changes, the value for custom field will get saved to **DB**

Answer (score 1):

Please try this and if not resolved let us know code of controller for save reviews

[image]

Comment: i have updated the controller function, and i did try as you suggest but still it is not saving custom fields to database.

Comment: let me know controller php code be sure that controller of core files not in local directory.

Comment: i have added code of my controller, i know do not edit with core files and i always work with local files, i appreciate you pointed on core file do not edit.

Comment: but in case of controllers you have to edit controller. so please do change your controller code of core .

Comment: can you give me instruction what to edit and where? or better if you update your answer.